# Saving Chrome instance

Tags: google-chrome, website

We have several Chrome accounts opened in different windows with my family. Within the same OS account. Some times if you closed Chrome in wrong order it doesn't save opened tabs, even pinned ones. Is there a way to save pinned tabs like a preset? I need a bunch of them for my work and kids keep closing them.

Thanks,
[Robert](https://www.reclinerland.com/)

Comment: Tried using Ctrl-Shift-T to re-open closed tabs? It can recover whole windows full of tabs too.

Comment: There are session manager addons that exists on the Chrome store.  The default session capability of Chrome is limited, if chrome doesn’t successfully restore a closed session, then it’s permanently gone.  I will not recommend any specific add-on

Answer (score 0):

If you close Chrome accidentally, a popup appears and says if you want to restore the tabs. In the User Data folder in Chrome AppData, there are two files named Last Tabs and Last Session and you can rename them from "Last" to "Current" by deleting Current ones.

Also as @Darius said you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.